# Convert 9 speeed Campagnolo Ergo Levers to 10 Speed

Tags: gears, campagnolo

A friend gave me a carbon set of campag record 9 speed ergos.  I would love to convert the 9 to 10 Speed and I understand it is possible.  I have read that some dealers will do it but the cost is almost same as new set of levers. Has anybody done it and was it difficult?

Answer (score 4):

It is not too difficult to rebuild campy leavers - although a extra set of hands can be handy for one of the steps where you need to hold a spring in position (there is a trick to it). You can get the parts if you ask around local shops or online and you can convert from 8 to 9 to 10 speed provided the internals are the same type - you should be OK as you have the 9 speed ones, 10 speed and up may different. The G springs were about $10 when I last braught a set and I have seen the cam/ratchet part online for arount $50 - but that was a while ago, and in Australia.

Look up the book "zin and the art of road bike maintaince" or rebuilding ergoleavers section on http://www.campyonly.com/ (right at the bottom). On the campagnolo website there are manuals that include exploaded diagrams of all their components and part numbers, and when I last looked had the ergo leavers had listed the part numbers you need to change the number of speeds.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this thread is pretty old but since I just went through this conversion I wanted to add what I learned.
Campagnolo changed the internals a little in 1999 so anything before that model year has to have a few extra parts to make the lever conversion but it can be done. This is for the right/rear shifter.
The actual 10-speed index gear was changed where the central pivot shaft passes through it. So in order to make an older style lever compatible with the new index gear the pivot shaft and a few associated parts need to be upgraded as well.

Central Pivot Shaft Assembly upgrade – Parts List
EC-RE435 Central Pivot Shaft
EC-RE407 Central Pivot Fixing Bolt
EC-RE251 Coil Spring Bushing
EC-RE149 Central Pivot Fixing Bolt Retention Washer
EC-AT061 Ergo Index Gear Bottom Washer
EC-RE008 Coil Spring Bushing Wear Prevention Washer
The Central Pivot Shaft was changed to improve reliability with the junction to the Coil Spring Bushing as well as fit the new center of the new 10-speed Ergo Index Gear. The Index Gear Bottom Washer provides correct spacing between the bearings in the hood and the new Index Gear. It also fits inside the recess on the Index gear. The Coil Spring Bushing Wear Prevention Washer has a different inner diameter than the old one so it must be replaced. The Central Pivot Fixing Bolt Retention Washer has a smaller center hole diameter that fits the smaller head of new Central Pivot Fixing Bolt which must be replaced to fit the new Central Pivot Shaft threads. It also uses a #15 Torx bit to tighten it, not the 3mm Allen that is stated in the Campy documentation. This makes up the parts needed to make older levers compatible with ‘99 and newer 10-speed.

With these parts any lever can be upgraded to the 10-speed setup. You will still need the 10-speed parts, the index gear, the ratchet ring, and the improved G Spring Carrier if yours hasn't already been replaced. There are some other suggested normal wear items on the list for rebuilds (springs, etc.) but they could be considered optional if yours are in good shape.

Good shifting to all that keep their (older) Campy stuff going.

Comment: That's a great answer - thank you for contributing.  You can include pictures too, if they help.  Please keep up the good work.